# Should i prune tomato fruiting trusses?

Tags: pruning, tomatoes

We all know to leave about 4 fruit trusses on a tomato plant and to prune out suckers and side shoots. But the ends of the fruiting trusses on my plants have turned up and shot up in the air like new side shoots. They still have fruit on but then they curl up and have a huge shoot on the end. Why is this happening? Is it normal, and should I prune these ends off?

Here are a couple of pictures. I've circled the fruiting trusses near the plant.  In both cases the truss and the plant are at the back, and you can see where it then has a new megashoot on the end coming towards the camera which is about 2 feet long an curves up!

Do you think I should cut these off?  I'm doubtful the plant can ripen all that fruit.

[image: tomato truss with megashoot on the end]

[image: another tomato truss with megashoot on the end]

Comment: When there's an excess of good growing conditions, I've seen trusses shoot out and grow new stems, and I've seen the ends of big leaves shoot out new stems. I think cutting them off would be the difference between many smaller fruits or fewer large ones. Seems to happen more in cherry tomatoes. Can we see a picture?

Comment: @J.Musser see above

Comment: @JStorage see above ^^

Comment: @NiallC. They are big beef.  See above.